# Inserting from SQL Server into MySQL results in first 2 rows blank

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data from a SQL Server table into a MySQL table; all columns insert correctly except for the first 2. I check the DB structure all matches. Recreated the tables, still have the same issue. Here is my statement:

```
insert openquery (MySQL, 'select  DB, CreateDate, TaxDate, DocEntry, WddStatus, DocStatus, CardName, DocCur, DocTotal, U_NAME, Comments from ODRF_New')
Select
DB
,CreateDate
,TaxDate
,DocEntry
,WddStatus
,DocStatus
,Cardname
,DocCur
,DocTotal
,U_NAME
,Comments

From mashova_intranet.dbo.ODRF_New
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide all information needed to duplicate your issue. Such things as the create scripts for the two tables and the specifics on each server.

Comment: I resolved the issue; it seems that there is a limitation on the amount of columns that I can insert, might be with the hosted service provider. As soon as I select more than 9 columns, then the 1st or 2nd columns is blank. Example:
Select DB to DocTotal (9 columns), insert works perfectly. Select DB to U_Name (10 columns), DB is blank after insert. Select DB to Comments (11 columns), DB and CreateDate is blank after insert. This does not make sense, thus my assumption that there is a limitation at the hosted service provider?